# ASP.NET Core tries to cast an object to System.Int64 when using LINQ GroupBy

Tags: linq, asp.net-core, casting

When trying to execute the following ASP.NET Core code:

```cs
public class Foo
{
    public long A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("Foos")]
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<IGrouping<long, Foo>>> Foos()
{
    var foos = new List<Foo> { new Foo { A = 1, B = "Foo" }, new Foo { A = 2, B = "Bar" }, new Foo { A = 2, B = "Baz" } };
    return new ActionResult<IEnumerable<IGrouping<long, Foo>>>(foos.GroupBy(f => f.A));
}
```

I get:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Foo' to type 'System.Int64'.
   at System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfoNotNullable`4.OnWriteEnumerable(WriteStackFrame& current, Utf8JsonWriter writer)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfo.WriteEnumerable(WriteStack& state, Utf8JsonWriter writer)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.HandleEnumerable(JsonClassInfo elementClassInfo, JsonSerializerOptions options, Utf8JsonWriter writer, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Int32 originalWriterDepth, Int32 flushThreshold, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteAsyncCore(Stream utf8Json, Object value, Type inputType, JsonSerializerOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter.WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context, Encoding selectedEncoding)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter.WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context, Encoding selectedEncoding)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|29_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Why does it seem to be trying to serialize an object to an int64? How can I successfully return the result of a GroupBy from a web API endpoint?

Comment: I'm not sure that serialization/deserialization of `IGrouping` is that much of a good idea, both in terms of the serializer itself, and in respect to the amount of domain information that it actually conveys to the developer.

Answer (score 0):

New `System.Text.Json` serializer cannot serialize `IEnumerable<IGrouping<long, Foo>>`.

#### Solution

I would recommend switching to old Json.Net serializer in your ASP.Net Core project. I've tested it and it works fine with Json.Net.

See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#newtonsoftjson-jsonnet-support) article for information about switching to Json.Net.

It will be something as easy as that:

```cs
services.AddMvc()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

Comment: "that object"? You mean the `IGrouping`? I have my doubts regarding the sanity of attempting to serialize/deserialize an `IGrouping`.

Comment: Yeah. I meant IGrouping. I also don't think this is "good" or "decent" practise to return IGrouping, but I just answered the question.